# Safe to delete or shrink old MBR System Reserved partition after conversion to GPT?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I've seen similar questions before, but never have I seen anyone seem to recognize the difference between the MBR and EFI boot partitions, so I'm asking fresh.

Basically, I just converted my disk to a GPT disk, doing it through mbr2gpt from within the OS because I don't have prepared install media. This tagged the new boot partition to the end of the data partition and left the old boot partition as a 500MB primary partition sitting at the front end of the disk.

Now, I need to make clear, because this is where every similar question I've seen previously go awry, this partition is no longer the boot partition. It's just data now. The thing is, I'm not sure how booting works here, and don't know how important it is that my boot partition remains exactly where it is.

So, the question is, now that my system uses the EFI System Partition to boot, is it now safe to delete or shrink the old, unused MBR boot partition, System Recovery?

Comment: Exactly what are the partition's parameters? What filesystem is it formatted as, and what files does it contain?

Comment: I'm currently cloning the drive, so I can't tell you what files it contains, but I can tell you that it's ntfs formatted, and no longer has the boot flag, now only being flagged as msftdata.

Comment: I can confirm first-hand that deleting the partition will break booting, even though it appears to be a redundant leftover from using `mbr2gpt` with `/allowFullOS` on an OS drive. I guess it's possible to use Startup repair from a Windows bootable USB stick to fix a non-bootable drive, but I haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

No. don’t delete the System Reserved partition.
System Reserved partition save the files which used for boot failure, unless you have an external repair disk, you can delete it. Or you will encrypt disk by BitLocker in the next step, because enable BitLocker will automatically create system reserved partition.

Comment: Isn't that only in the case of a MBR drive?

Comment: @Paynamia - **DO NOT DELETE THE PARTITION** it has nothing to do with  your conversion to GPT